# Combining "exists" and "forall" expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to combine an "exists" and a "forall" expressions for a same variable?

ex.:

$(\forall e \mid e \in S \Rightarrow e \in T) \vee(\exists e \mid e \in S \wedge e \notin T)$

Combining $2$ foralls or $2$ exists is simple, but what if it is a mix of both?

Comment: Why are you using the same symbol for both quantifiers? That seems like an easy way to get confused.

Comment: @StellaBiderman, on the contrary; it greatly increases clarity as both parts of the statement are about elements of set $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your example is a contradiction. Consequently, if you're trying to combine those two, in particular, then you should stop trying (or, rather, **show** that there is a contradiction).

More generally, you just need to determine under what circumstances both may hold, if any such circumstances exist. One thing that often helps is the equivalence (assuming [excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)) of the following two statement types (for any statement $\Phi$ depending on $p\in J$):

1. $\forall p\in J,\Phi(j)$
2. $\neg\left(\exists p\in J:\Phi(j)\right)$

---

**Added**: As pointed out in the comments below, my first paragraph ***cannot*** be more wrong! Rather, the combined statement is simply true, regardless of $e, S$ and $T.$

Comment: It's not a contradiction; it's a tautology.  Stated in English, it says: "Either $S$ is a subset of $T$, or it is not."

Comment: @Wildcard: You are quite right! I thought the connective was an "and," rather than an "or." /sigh/