# How to demonstrate the subset definition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

I'm having a hard time trying to demonstrate the definition of a subset, which is :

$S \subseteq T \Leftrightarrow (S \subset T) \vee (S = T)$

I always end up by expending the definitions of $\subset$ and $=$ in Boolean algebra, resulting into [this complicated situation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455044/combining-exists-and-forall-expressions/).

Any way to solve it by staying in the Set theory? Or in Boolean algebra?

Comment: Do you mean expanding?  Right to left proof is obvious.  From left to right there are two cases:  S /= T;  S = T.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right way!

Your definition of $S \subset T$ as $\forall x (x \in S \rightarrow x \in T) \land \exists x (x \in T \land \neg x \in S)$ should work fine.

For $S = T$ you can use $\forall x (x \in S \leftrightarrow x \in T)$

And for $S \subseteq T$ you can use $\forall x (x \in S \rightarrow x \in T)$

Using these definitions, you should be able to prove $S \subseteq T \leftrightarrow (S \subset T \lor S =T)$ just fine.

Comment: Actually I have made a little mistake. The thing is that I start by proving the $\Rightarrow$, supposing that $S \subseteq T$ is true, then for the right-side equation, the simplification results in $(\exists e \mid e \in S \wedge e \notin T) \vee (\forall e \mid e \in T \Rightarrow e \in S)$, from which I'm totally unable to continue...

Comment: @lolgab123 What you have there is not the simplification of the right-side. To peove the right side from the left side, consider that either $\exists x (x \in T \land \neg x \in S)$ or $\neg \exists x (x \in T \land \neg x \in S)$